# Boost socket async_send: how does it handle ewouldblock?

Tags: sockets, boost, boost-asio

On Unix, send() on a non-blocking socket could return error EWOULDBLOCK if outbound socket buffer is full. In this case, one should call select() to determine when it's possible to retry. Does Boost sockets in nonblocking mode handle all of this for you?

Comment: EWOUDLBLOCK only arises in non-blocking mode. Async mode is not non-blocking mode. It is akin to blocking mode on a separate thread.

Comment: I should clarify, I am using the boost socket in non-blocking mode (I set non_blocking(true)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does. You can check for yourself for example here `boost/asio/detail/impl/socket_ops.ipp`.